# Is there an upper limit on the amount of money you can spend in Nintendo Badge Arcade?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-badge-arcade

I didn't think this game would hook me the way it did. I've purchased 65 tokens in the game so far and will not likely stop.  However, I'm worried that I may end up spending too much on the game in its lifetime.

I've dabbled in another "free-to-start" game that had a limit, Pokemon Rumble World.  In that game, you could only purchase 30000 gems (approximately the cost of a standard 3DS game) at which point, you can no longer purchase any more.  The game would give you gems for free on a daily basis.

Does Nintendo Badge Arcade have a similar system where if I were to buy a certain amount of coins, I won't be allowed to buy any more and will be given free plays afterwards?

I don't mind "purchasing" the game, but I hate the idea that there is no end to how much I'll be milked for this.

Comment: I fear it's really a money-milking game...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, considering I've managed to purchase well over $100 USD worth of tokens, it doesn't seem like there is a limit.  The amount spent far exceeds the amount I spent on Pokemon Rumble World (which was ~$32 USD), tt exceeds the cost of a typical 3DS game (~$40 USD), and exceeds the cost of a typical console game (~$50-$60 USD) and beyond.

It looks like there's no end to it at this moment.

I would *hope* that if they did stop introducing new badges and someone managed to collect all of them, they would be free to play whenever they chose.  But we won't know that now, at least until the time comes.  Hopefully there'll be some incentive when the NX inevitably comes and more official Nintendo mobiles games get released.

Answer (score 0):

No, Unfortunalty there doesnt seem like there is an upper bound, the issue is they will undoubtedly want to squeeze every penny out of people who use the systems to cover the fact that the New 3DS wasnt as immediately popular as they expected it to be.

I havent really found myself overly addicted to badge arcade but I can see why people do. But it looks like for not there wont be any limit to how much you can spend on it. Which if everyone who has gotten addicted to it spends as much as I have heard people have been spending on it, this trend of unlimited spending in games might be a permenant feature in the future.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything that the existing answer didn't already cover.

Comment: As a side note, I'd never even heard of microtransaction games having a spending cap until Nintendo started doing it, so this seems more like a step AWAY from unlimited spending, with Nintendo Badge Arcade being an exception among their games.